# Paypal paywall customize text css

Tags: javascript, css, paypal

I am new to adding integrations with paypal into a website, I have been able to successfully setup the smart button on a sandbox account, however I am looking to customize the labels since the paypal gets render on a dark background and I can't seem to figure it out.

I have attached a screenshot, in it you can see "Billing Address", is it possible to change the css font color of this label?

Thanks in advance :)[image: Paywall]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no customization options for this. Here is the relevant documentation page: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/standard-card-fields/#

As you can see it doesn't give any styling options, and it is a PayPal frame cannot control.

You can control whether or not the black Debit/Credit card button shows, and you can control its shape, height, whether it stretches to max width, and the width and background color of your own container.